# Why is a new CMD window opened on using command START in cmd to open an MP3 file?

Tags: cmd

When I type in a Windows CMD window on which a MINGW64 remote desktop connection session was started before

```
start 'Vicetone - Nevada (ft. Cozi Zuehlsdorff).mp3'
```

to open an MP3 file, a new CMD window is opened instead of playing the MP3 file. The new CMD window displays in title bar:

> Administrator: Vicetone - Nevada (ft. Cozi Zuehlsdorff).mp3

I can successfully open image files using `start` this way.

Is there a way to play MP3's from `cmd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the syntax of the `start` command in batch file is as follows:

```bat
start /options "title_of_new_window" "file_to_start" -Arguments
```

- If `"title_of_new_window"` (title to be displayed in window title bar) is empty, the `"file_to_start"` will decide which the title will be.
- If `"file_to_start"` is empty, then a new cmd window will open.

Double quotes should be used in both cases.

So, you should write something like this:

```bat
start "" "Vicetone - Nevada (ft. Cozi Zuehlsdorff).mp3"
```

Type `start /?` in a fresh command-line for more information.